# Getting infinite "wrong answer" as output on ideone

Tags: exception, python-3.4, eof

```
import sys
def carton(x):
    bottle=x/10
    rem=x%10
    if rem > 7:
        bottle = bottle + rem + 1
    elif rem == 7:
        bottle = bottle + 1
    elif 5<rem<7:
        bottle = bottle + 2
    elif rem == 5:
        bottle = bottle + 1
    elif rem<5:
        bottle = bottle + rem
    print (bottle)

def carton_small(x):
    bottle = 0
    if x > 7:
        bottle = bottle + x%7 + 1
    elif x == 7:
        bottle = bottle + 1
    elif 5<x<7:
        bottle = bottle + 2
    elif x == 5:
        bottle = bottle + 1
    elif x<5:
        bottle = x
    print(bottle)
while True:
    test = sys.stdin.read()
    try:
        test = int(test)
    except ValueError:
        print ("no, wrong data")
        continue
    except EOFError:
        print ("no,EOF")
        continue
    if not test: break
    break
for x in range(test):
    while True:
         bottle = sys.stdin.read()
    try:
         bottle = int(bottle)
    except ValueError:
        print ("no, wrong data")
        continue
    except EOFError:
        print ("no, EOF1")
        continue
    if not test: break
        break
if(bottle>10):
    carton(bottle)
elif(bottle<10):
    carton_small(bottle)
else:
    bottle = 1
    print (bottle)
```

I wrote the code to check the minimum number of bottles requrired by the milkman to carry x litre of milk. The bottles are of size {1,5,7,10} litres only. Things are working fine on my system but on Ideone, I am getting the error defined in my valueError exception infinitely.Anyhelp possible please?
I am sure the problem is because of sys.stdin.readline() here as input was doing just fine but ideone doesn't accept input() i guess.

Comment: Could you indent properly please?

Comment: It would be helpful if you copied the error so we can see what's going on...

Comment: stdin copy
Standard input is empty
  stdout copy
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no, wrong data
no,